# How do you enable/show the Host tab in Glimpse?

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

How do you enable/show the Host tab in Glimpse? It shows up in one of my projects but not in another, yet I can't see any configuration item which would cause the host tab to be enabled. If I click the "g" I can all the relevant details appearing (SQL etc) but it's useful to have the info on the HUD too.

Host tab missing:

[image: Glimpse missing Host tab]

It should look like this:

[image]

I'm using:
Glimpse.Core 1.30
Glimpse.ADO 1.7.3
Glimpse.ASPNET 1.9.2  under WebForms.

Comment: do you see js errors in the console?

Comment: Nope - console is clean.

Comment: Is any data in the SQL tab?

Comment: Yep - the SQL tab is working fine and shows SQL calls. It's only the HUD which has a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also install [`Glimpse.WebForms`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.WebForms/).

The `Glimpse.AspNet` package contains a few tabs and useful abstractions across both MVC and WebForms, but nothing specific to the "Host" section of HUD.

Comment: Nik is right. I miss read what you had above and thought that you already had it installed, but you need the WinForms package for that section to show up.

Comment: I'm struggling to install Glimpse.WebForms.  Nuget says it's already installed after I search for it (and won't let me install) yet it doesn't appear in the list of installed packages.

Comment: OK - it not sure what happened, but the WebForms package didn't seem to be installed properly. I've removed and re-added it and now the Host tab is appearing. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad your sorted!